# Spring transaction manager with jdbc template and entity manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I migrated few calls in my entity to use jdbc but few calls still use hibernate entity manager.
MyObjectEntity class

```
    public static List<MyObject> findByIdAndListOfVersions{
         new jdbcTemplate.query(myquery);
    }

  public static List<MyObject> findById{
         new jdbcTemplate.query(myquery);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void persist() {
        EntityManagerAccessor.getEntityManager().persist(this);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void flush() {
        EntityManagerAccessor.getEntityManager().flush();
    }
```

Somewhere in my code.I am trying to use mix and match

```
MyObjectEntity.findbyId();
MyObjectEntity.merge();
MyObjectEntity.flush();
MyObjectEntity.findByIdAndListOfVersions();
```

Problem is before moving to jdbc I was getting some objects as result now I get them as empty.Not sure this might be issue with transaction.We are in process of migration from jpa to jdbc dao hence these is mix and match of both.One thing I  noticed was  my method was static and creating new jdbcTemplate instead of autowiring.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? also, why are you using both?

Comment: What is the `jdbcTemplate` you have? Theoretically, rather than creating new instance, you should `autowire` in JdbcTemplate(with datasource) since it is a singleton that won't change state once it's set.